# gnome-terminal will not load - can access via VSCode

Tags: command-line

ThinkPad T470s, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, GNOME 42.5 plenty of memory and disk space. Haven't used my thinkpad in a while. Booted it up, installed some updates and can no longer open Terminal. Click on the icon and it just spins and then closes.

I can access Terminal through VSCode. I've tried the remote-chrome-desktop suggestion but no luck. [gnome-terminal will not load, sudo gnome-terminal will](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083265/gnome-terminal-will-not-load-sudo-gnome-terminal-will)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I removed Terminal, and it auto loaded xterm so I'm going with that for the moment. I also loaded fish shell.

Comment: What happens if you try `gnome-terminal` into your xterm?