# Weird issue with no Sound on Ubuntu 19.04 / Terminal, Files and screenshot unable to start up

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, 19.04

Encountered this weird issue where after upgrading to 19.04, my sound setting are all heywire. Plus some app wouldnt able to run like starting terminal, files and screenshot.

After some digging, realized that it might be related to some app crashing causing both the sound issue and also the app issue. The app of concern is either **Anydesk** or **Kazam** which I had already remove and purge from my laptop.
Quite stuck now on how to go about debugging this. I had no idea where the root cause of the bug is and seems like there is multiple bugs happening.

Before the crash, the system was working fine with no issue, able to use the sound, the headphones as well as recording etc. It was only after installing **Kazam** and did some recording and had a reboot that all this problem start to crop up.

I found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure. I am not sure whether to proceed with this as the current bug seems quite unique.

I explored the solution on installing pulseaudio, reloading alsa and even rename ~/.config/pulse/ but to no avail. Sound still not set by default. The cards and headphones are detected as it as show below:

Checking using `aplay -l` shows all the hardware detected so I believe the issue should be on the software side. The detected also included my usb connected headphones **(Sennheiser Main Audio)**
[image]

Pic: Sound issue:

The output device shows the setting after I had installed pulseaudio and did a `pulseaudio -- start`. However, my headphone config setting is not shown.
[image]

App unable to start issue:

Terminal, Files and Screenshot unable to start each time I reboot or restart my laptop. I had a workaround now which is to change the region & languages setting and then logout and login again to be able to start the terminal which is a bit of a hassle to do everytime.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching I finally found the root of the problems. IT was chrome remote desktop all along. I uninstalled it via and was about to get my headphones working. Speaker still dont work so I am trying to see how to reset my audio setting.

```
sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop
```

[Installing Google Chrome Remote Desktop messed up my box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963756/installing-google-chrome-remote-desktop-messed-up-my-box)