# Audio issue with Samsung NP350E5C

Tags: sound

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS at my old laptop Samsung NP350E5C-S05.
A little strange but sometimes I have audio issue.

It happens especially when I turn on the laptop. I try playing music / YouTube video but nothing plays.
When I run audio settings and run through cards like "Input, Output, Sound effects, Programs" sound works (two times, sometimes one).

After that sound works perfect, as long as I don't need to reboot the machine. In the long perspective it is really frustrating.
I have another PC with Debian(gnome) and something like that doesn't happen there at all.

Previously I had Ubuntu 16.04 with the same problem.

`lspci`:

[image: lspci]

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved.

Comment: Would you please write an answer below and show how you solved it so others with the same issue can benefit. Thank you

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/963756/installing-google-chrome-remote-desktop-messed-up-my-box#1028950